# Why does this not dm the warned user?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
const toki1 = require('./something')
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const mod = new Discord.Client
let somearray = []

mod.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('I am ready. Please work I beg you')
})
mod.on('message', msg => {
    let linesplit = msg.content.split('\n')
    let unchanged = msg.content.split(' ')
    if(unchanged[0] != '*bot5' && !msg.author.bot){
       let thotus = msg.content.toLowerCase()
       somearray.forEach(swear => {
           
           let white = new RegExp(swear, "g")
           thotus = thotus.replace(white, `||${swear}||`)  
       }) 
       if (somearray.some(v => msg.content.toLowerCase().includes(v))) {
           
           msg.channel.send(`Sent by: ${msg.author.tag}, Censored by: MRModeration(bot 5)\n${thotus}`)
                .then(whil => {
                    msg.delete({timeout: 400})
                })
                .catch(rer => {
                  msg.channel.send(`we catched something\nget it\nbecause .catch()\n\nThe error is ${rer}`)
                  msg.delete({timeout: 400})
              
              
              })
       }
    
    } 
    if(unchanged[0] == '*bot5'){
        if(msg.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR') || msg.member.roles.cache.has('724326097306779699')){
        
        if(!unchanged[1]){
            msg.reply('you need something to do with this bot')
            return;
        } 
        switch(unchanged[1]){
            case 'msgdelete':
                
                if(!unchanged[2]){
                    msg.reply('you need something to send')
                    return;
                }
                if(isNaN(unchanged[2])){
                    msg.reply('you need a number')
                    return;
                }
                if(Number(unchanged[2]) < 1 || Number(unchanged[2]) > 100){
                    msg.reply('the amount needs to be between 1 and 100')
                    return;
                }
                if(!Number.isInteger(Number(unchanged[2]))){
                    msg.reply('it needs to be an integer(for obvious reasons)')
                    return;
                }

                    
                msg.channel.bulkDelete(Number(unchanged[2]) + 1, true)
                    .then(deleted => msg.channel.send(`I(bot 5) have deleted ${deleted.size - 1} message(s).`))
                    .catch(err => msg.reply(`something went wrong... \n\n **The presented error is** \n\n ${err}`))
                    
                
                break;
            case 'add':
                if(msg.member.roles.cache.has('730496872992735253')){
                if(!unchanged[2]){
                    msg.reply('what is it that you want to add???')
                } else {
                    let change = unchanged
                    change.splice(0, 2)
                    if(msg.author.bot){
                        return;
                    }
                    if(change.join(' ').length == 1 || change.join(' ').includes('|')){
                        msg.channel.send("this is either a letter, something that includes |.")
                        return;
                    }
                    
                    if(somearray.includes(change.join(' ').toLowerCase())){
                        msg.reply('already there')
                    } else {
                       somearray.push(change.join(' ').toLowerCase()) 
                       msg.channel.send(`${change.join(' ').toLowerCase()} is now in the list of swear words`)
                    }
                }
                } else {
                msg.channel.send('you do not have the role for this.')
                }
                break;
            case 'remove':
                if(msg.member.roles.cache.has('730496872992735253')){
                if(!unchanged[2]){
                    msg.reply('what is it that you want to remove???')
                } else {
                    let changer = unchanged
                    changer.splice(0, 2)

                    if(!somearray.includes(changer.join(' '))){
                        msg.reply('not an item that exists')
                    } else {
                        let sarray = somearray.filter(thing => thing != changer.join(' '))
                        somearray = sarray
                        msg.channel.send(`${changer.join(' ')} is now removed from the list of swear words`)
                    }
                }
                } else {
                msg.channel.send('you do not have the role for this.')
                }
                break;
            default:
                msg.reply('not a command yet')
                break;
            
        }
        } else {
            msg.reply('you are neither an admin nor a moderator.')
                .then(good => {
                    good.delete({ timeout: 3000 })
                    msg.delete({ timeout: 6000 })
                .catch(err => {
                    msg.channel.send(`Seemingly an error appeared\n\n***__badumm__***\n***__badumm__***\n***__badumm__***\n the error is \n\n ${err}`)
                })
                
                })
            
        }
        

    }
    if(msg.content.startsWith('*swearwords')){
        const joiner = somearray.join('\n')
        const embid = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('All swear words in the list') 
            .attachFiles('./yesyesyes.png')
            .setImage("attachment://yesyesyes.png")   
            .addField('*All swear words*', `[\n${joiner}\n]`)
        msg.channel.send(embid)
                
            
        
    }
    if(linesplit[0] == '*warn'){
        if(msg.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR') || msg.member.roles.cache.has('724326097306779699')){
            if(linesplit.length < 3){
                msg.channel.send(`you need *warn, then on another line the user's tag and another line the warn`)
                return;
            }
            if(msg.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.user.tag == linesplit[1])){
                if(msg.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.user.tag == linesplit[1]).hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR') || msg.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.user.tag == linesplit[1]).roles.cache.has('724326097306779699')){
                    msg.reply(`you can't warn admins or mods`)
                } else {
                    let grad = linesplit
                    a.splice(0, 2)
                    let gradon = grad.join('\n')
                    msg.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.user.tag == linesplit[1]).user.send(`__***Warned by: ${msg.author.tag}***__\nThe warning is(because):\n${gradon}`)
                }

            } else {
                msg.reply(`not a user's tag`)
            }
        } else {
            msg.reply('not allowed')
        }
    }         
})
mod.login(process.env.token)
```

My idea is a warn system that works like this

```
*warn
the tag of the user
the reason for the warn.
```

(the command is in the end)
I also put a lot of if statements to check if everything is used correctly like the one that checks if the warner. I probably should of not nested them though.

The problem I have is that it is not DMing the user with the tag. It is not producing an error either.

```
msg.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.user.tag == linesplit[1]).user.send(`__***Warned by: ${msg.author.tag}***__\nThe warning is(because):\n${gradon}`)
```

How do I make this line send the message to this members DM.

Answer (score 0):

Constant user will search for mention || tag (e.g. `hydrabolt#0001`) || id (e.g `42040040400404`).

No matter what you provide it will search for the member in the guild

```js
    if(linesplit[0] == '*warn'){
        if(msg.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR') || msg.member.roles.cache.has('724326097306779699')){
            if(linesplit.length < 3){
                msg.channel.send(`you need *warn, then on another line the user's tag and another line the warn`)
                return;
            }
            const user = msg.mentions.members.first() || msg.guild.members.cache.find(u => u.user.tag.toLowerCase() == linesplit[1].toLowerCase()) || msg.guild.members.cache.get(linesplit[1]) 
            if(!user) return msg.reply('not allowed')    
            if(user.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR') || user.roles.cache.has('724326097306779699')){
                    msg.reply(`you can't warn admins or mods`)
                } else {
                    let grad = linesplit
                    grad.splice(0, 2)
                    let gradon = grad.join('\n')
                    user.send(`__***Warned by: ${msg.author.tag}***__\nThe warning is(because):\n${gradon}`)
                }
    }         
 }
```

Comment: I tried doing it with the tag and the mention but it didn't send any dm(I am testing this bot with an alt account and the alt account is not getting any dms)

Comment: I did actually. Oh. simple enough. a is not defined. Idk why but I had in place a instead of grad. That should be a simple fix

Comment: I didn't see any error but still doesn't work exactly. It started not responding when I didn't have 3 lines minimum(it responds when I have 1 line but not 2). And it didn't dm when I used the tag. If I can't get this fixed I will probably just watch a tutorial on how to do this.